# How to install Ubuntu 18.10 to an UEFI system with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I did a lot of search but things looked very complex, I just cannot believe it will be such difficult.  So I think some tutorial may be written long time ago and thing could already became easier. To be pretty clear what I should do, I have to raise this maybe duplicated question.

I am a Slackware user, had no experience in Ubuntu.  I just got a new laptop installed with Windows 10. I then bought a new SSD disk for it and decided to install Ubuntu 18.10 onto this new disk and dual boot the laptop along with the existed Windows 10.  The windows 10 is booted by EFI and I've already disabled 'fast boot' in Windows.

I dumped (dd) the Ubuntu 18.10 to an USB stick and booted it to execute the installation.  I did not see any options like 'install alongside windows', so I choose to manually create partitions and told the installer the mount points. Of course, I did every thing on the new disk, did not change anything on the old disk that hosted Windows 10. Basically, I created three partitions, one for root, one for home and one as swap.  The installation went so smooth and it can even detect the Internet connection. Just after a while, the installation completed.  But the real problem I met is, there is not a new EFI boot option after reboot the laptop. Whatever I tried, it seemed like I've already installed the Ubuntu, but just cannot boot it.

What should I do?  Some net tutorials said I have to erase everything and install Ubuntu first, this is not an option to me. I can erase the 2nd disk, but cannot damage the first disk, because this is my company's computer. IT department will not install Windows for me after the laptop has already installed a Linux.

Please someone help. Thanks.
woody

Comment: Which device/system are you using?

Comment: Some brands need additional settings/changes. But did you install in UEFI boot mode? Did you make SSD for Ubuntu as gpt and include an ESP - efi system partition. If you installed in UEFI mode, grub would have installed to ESP on Windows drive, but otherwise not modified Windows. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not post full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I don't know about dual-disk dual-boot but I think both the SSD & bootable USB drive have to be GPT partitioned disk. I think you can make/make sure SSD is GPT partitioned using Easeus Partition Master Free. You can make USB device GPT partitioned Ubuntu install-able media using Rufus. The installer probably didn't see the Windows installation because the UBS wasn't GPT partitioned.

Comment: The laptop is a Dell Precision 5530, the new disk is a Samsung 750 EVO NVME m.2.  What means USB need to be GPT partitioned?  I just 'dd if=the-install-dvd.iso' of=/dev/sdc bs=2048' to create the boot USB, is it correct?  I think my ESP was in my first disk, say /dev/sda1.  Did you guys mean I should mount this partition and answer the installer to put the boot loader into this mounted partition?  BTW: I did not find ppa after I boot into live Ubuntu. I will erase my partition and use gpartd to repartition the disk before retry.  Thanks I will come back.